# Why does my django allow downloading files outside of static folder?

Tags: django

My `django` project allows downloding images from static folder:

http://0.0.0.0:8001/static/img/login.png

This makes sense.

But what concerns me is that it also allows me downloading files even outside of the static folder such as:

http://0.0.0.0:8000/logs/result.log

or even worse:

http://0.0.0.0:8000/users/models.py

All my local files can be downloaded via clients.

This is a high security vulnerability. No matter what is the permission of my folders on my Linux server. I do not have such items in my path and I do not expect these paths being served.

How can I fix this?

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

DEBUG = True

INSTALLED_APPS = [
        'comments',
        'home',
        'users',
        'articles',
        'notifications',
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'static_precompiler',
        'django_markup',
        'django_minify_html',
        'django_rename_app',
    ]

MIDDLEWARE = [
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django_minify_html.middleware.MinifyHtmlMiddleware',
    ]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'profplus.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': ["templates"],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'profplus.wsgi.application'


STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
        'static_precompiler.finders.StaticPrecompilerFinder',
    ]
```

Comment: What's your `STATICFILES_DIRS` setting?

Comment: Could you try and disable `'static_precompiler...'` value from the finders to check whether it's causing this issue?

Comment: @xyres, there is no `STATICFILES_DIRS` set. Also, tried disabling `static_precompiler` just by commenting it out and restarting Django. The problem still happens.

Answer (score 1):

According to the official docs: [how to manage static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/):

> In addition to these configuration steps, you’ll also need to actually serve the static files.

> During development, if you use django.contrib.staticfiles, this will be done automatically by runserver when DEBUG is set to True (see django.contrib.staticfiles.views.serve()).

> This method is grossly inefficient and ***probably insecure, so it is unsuitable for production.***

That being said, **no-one cares about the security of serving static files in Django and you shouldn't be using it in production**. Use a dedicated server to serve static files, [how to deploy static files in production](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/deployment/)

Comment: Do you mean that Django static file serving is inherently insecure?

Comment: @ar2015 yes, you should not use Django static file serving mechanism in production.

Comment: What to use instead?

Comment: @ar2015 collectstatic + nginx, did you read the last link above?

Comment: I would like to serve the media files on the same server but via nginx. Is this possible? What settings should I adjust?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a typo here?

```
TEMPLATES = TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

It should just have one word TEMPLATES and DIRS should be an ABSOLUTE path like this:

```
 TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

In production, you can use Nginx to deploy your app and if set up correctly, all the paths that are not declared in urls.py should be denied.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I just realized that not just TEMPLATES has an extra word in there, but also MIDDLEWARE and STATICFILES_FINDERS. Please remove those as well.

Comment: Sorry, my typo when writing the question. I fixed the question. In reality there is only single word.

Comment: No worries. Can you also post the **urlpatterns** in your urls.py and views.py on your user app?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't configure static files settings properly for production. You should serve static files directly in Nginx.

nginx config:

```
server {
    ....
    location /static/ {
          alias /app/staticfiles/;
    }
}
```

when a request is sent to /static/ -- e.g, /static/base.css -- Nginx will attempt to serve the file from the "/app/staticfiles/" folder.

links for more info:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/
https://testdriven.io/blog/django-static-files/

Comment: This links provides too much confusing information than being helpful. I still do not understand how Django and Apache work together. Unfortunately none of the provided answers are complete.

Answer (score 0):

The builtin static file server is not intended for production use, so it makes no effort to deal with security issues like the one you mention. Normally, static files are not served by any Python application -- static files are typically offloaded to a server or service specialized for serving static files, such as a traditional webserver (Apache, NGINX, etc) or a CDN (CloudFlare, CloudFront, Azure Frontdoor, etc). This is described [in the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/deployment/).

If you don't have a CDN and don't want to use a separate server for static files and you *must* use your Python application to serve static files, you can use the [whitenoise middleware](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/) in your Django project instead.

Install the package:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Then add it to your project:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    # ...
]
```

And remove the `STATICFILES_FINDERS` setting you have currently.

Check the whitenoise docs for more information and configuration options.

Comment: I tried it. It does not work and give 404 error. Many other people have the same problem and they have found no solution.

Comment: @ar2015 did you run `collectstatic` after making the changes? Check the whitenoise documentation. I just tested it on a simple project and it works as expected... Note also that the order of the middleware matters!

Comment: I ran `collectstatic`. I can see the image in the path and yet it does issue 404. I used exactly the same order too.

Comment: Can I create my own app to serve static files? My site structure is simple. Multiple app but I add the image files manually to statics folder. Using nginx looks too much redundant to me.

Comment: Uploaded my MWE [here](https://file.io/JKIzZLl1ArrX). It does not work as expected and gives 404 when loading . Would you mind have a look at it? I load the URL http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/ and the image does not appear. It is strange that the image URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/images/hi.jpg instead of referring to staticfiles folder.

Comment: I found a problem using the full path like `application = WhiteNoise(application, root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")  )` works now. It is for debug mode. When turning debug mode, I get error 500. No console message. But if I turn on the logs, it shows: `ValueError: Missing staticfiles manifest entry for 'images/hi.jpg'`. While it was working fine for the debug mode. If any image fails via whitenoise, does it prevent loading the whole page?

Comment: Fixed the server error by `WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False` in settings.py. But images do not show up as whitenoise adds strange numbers in front of the image file name. Any way to turn it off?

Comment: Worked after full path like `application = WhiteNoise(application, root=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")  )` and adding `WHITENOISE_MANIFEST_STRICT = False` and `STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage"`.

Comment: It now works in prod mode but not debug mode. [link](https://file.io/SClJMakWTBxj)
So confusing.

Comment: @ar2015 make sure you don't have staticfile routes in your `urls.py`. Sounds like you got it working otherwise. If the answer was helpful to your original question, please consider accepting it. If you still have issues with whitenoise, consider opening a separate question for that issue :)